# How to get the validate the count with the group by data in unix

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I have a list of records as following

Source:

```
a,yes
a,yes
b,No
c,N/A
c,N/A
c,N/A
d,xyz
d,abc
d,abc
```

Output:

```
a, Yes 2
b, No 1
c, N/A 3
d, xyz 1
d, abc 2

c, N/A "File is not correct"
```

Here 'Yes' and 'No' are the acceptable words, If any other word count is greater than the 'Yes' or 'No' word count for an individual $1 value then we have issue a statement like "file is not good"

I have tried the below script

```
awk -F, '{a[$1]++;}END{for (i in a)print i, a[i];}' filetest.txt
```

Comment: Do you have a question?  Also, what have you tried and what isn't working about what you tried?

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: `awk -F, '{a[$1]++;}END{for (i in a)print i, a[i];}' filetest.txt ` which I have tried

Comment: This question is a bit terse I'm afraid. You need to mention how many values are allowed for `$1` ( Is it just a,b,c ? ). Also the solution you've provided doesn't address the problem at all, looks like you added it for the sake of adding a solution.

Comment: Nope ! It is just a sample data.

Comment: @EdMorton I have updated the question!

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not worried about the output sequence(same as Input_file) then following may help you in same.

```
awk -F, '{array[$1", "$2]++;} /yes/{y++;next} /No/{n++;next} /N\/A/{count++;next} END{;for(i in array){printf("%s %s%s\n",i,array[i],(count>y && count>n) && i ~ /N\/A/?RS i" File is not correct":"")}}'  Input_file
```

**EDIT:** Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk -F, '{
array[$1", "$2]++;
}
/yes/{
  y++;
  next
}
/No/{
  n++;
  next
}
/N\/A/{
  count++;
  next
}
END{;
  for(i in array){
     printf("%s %s%s\n",i,array[i],(count>y && count>n) && i ~ /N\/A/?RS i" File is not correct":"")
}
}'  Input_file
```

**EDIT2:** As per OP N/A shouldn't be hardcoded then following code will check count of string yes, count of string no and count of rest of the second fields. Then it will compare count of rest with yes and no, based on that it will print the lines as per OP's request.

```
awk -F, '{
array[$1", "$2]++;
}
/yes/{
  y++;
  next
}
/No/{
  n++;
  next
}
{
  count[$2]++;
}
END{
  for(i in count){
    val=val>count[i]?val:count[i]
};
  for(i in array){
    printf("%s %s%s\n",i,array[i],(val>y && val>n) &&(i !~ /yes/ && i !~ /No/)?RS i" File is not correct":"")
}
}'   Input_file
```

After running above code I am getting following.

```
./script.ksh
d, xyz 1
d, xyz File is not correct
c, N/A 3
c, N/A File is not correct
b, No 1
a, yes 2
d, abc 2
d, abc File is not correct
```

Comment: I should Concentrate on 'Yes' and  'No' count, If any other count is greater that Yes and No count then we should report.(Always Yes and No count should only more for a good file)

Comment: try my edited one now and let me know if this helps you.

Comment: We can hard code Yes and No but not any other value. we can take count of group by of $1 and $2 Column and see the highest count, If the highest count of $2 is not Yes or No, Then we have to report

Comment: @Bobby: Try my edited version now and let me know then.

Comment: As I have asked , We should not hard code except 'Yes' and 'No', I have updated the input sample data. Could you please check .

Comment: What is that, see your comments above, you had mentioned we can hardcode, yes and no so only I changed my code(My previous solution was not hardcoded one.). Please be clear in your requirements. Also you could try it with your new data, it should work, if it is not working please let me know then.

Comment: yeah! We Should not hard code any word EXCEPT 'Yes' and 'No'  ! This means We should hard code only 'YES' and 'NO'.

Comment: Did you try my code, it looks it should give you expected results only, let me know on same.

Comment: check my edit2 now and let me know if that helps you.

Comment: I still see the 'N/A' is hard coded in the final statement. I still see N/A in the answer even if the other words has more count.

Comment: Edited now check and let me know how it goes then.

Comment: Still not working bro!! Now it is showing 'File is not correct' for every record

Comment: Sorry for delay, try EDIT2 now and let me know if that helps. It should work now and NO hardcoding for NO and YES strings too.

Comment: Nope!!. It is just as earlier code showing  'File is not correct'  for all the records except for YES and NO, It is not comparing the counts I guess!!

Comment: I am getting EXACT output, see my edit now where I have added the output of script.ksh too now, let me know.

Comment: We should not get the File not correct for 'abc' and 'xyz' as those both count are same or less count when compared to Yes and No count. We should report only if the any word count is greater than 'yes' or 'no' count.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for true multi-dimensional arrays:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=","; OFS=", " }
{ cnt[$1][$2]++ }
END {
    for (key in cnt) {
        for (val in cnt[key]) {
            cur = cnt[key][val]
            print key, val " " cur
            if (tolower(val) ~ /^(yes|no)$/) {
                maxGood = (maxGood > cur ? maxGood : cur)
            }
            else {
                badCnt[key][val] = cur
            }
        }
    }

    print ""
    for (key in badCnt) {
        for (val in badCnt[key]) {
            if (badCnt[key][val] > maxGood) {
                print key, val " File is not correct"
            }
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
a, yes 2
b, No 1
c, N/A 3
d, abc 2
d, xyz 1

c, N/A File is not correct
```

Use `tolower()` in other places or remove it as appropriate if your $2 data really can be upper or lower case or if that's just a mistake in your example and depending on if you want that treated as an error or not.

The output will be in random order courtesy of the `in` operator - that's easily changed to any other order if you care.

Answer (score -2):

```
#!/bin/sh

FILE=1.txt

for r in `cat $FILE | sort | uniq`; do
count=`grep "$r" "$FILE" | wc -l | sed -e 's/^ *//'`
echo "$r $count";
done
```